# In Java, How to sort an object recursively if it contains a list of same object type

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

My Object looks like this

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String name;
    private List<Person> child;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Person> getChild() {
        return child;
    }
    public void setChild(List<Person> child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", child=" + child + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
    
}
```

Consider it as a family. There is a one root person. He has some children and those children has some children and so on.
I want to sort it in such a way that if I get the child list of the root person all the Person under that should be sorted based on the name alphabetically and recursively to al the nestings below that. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If `C` has children `A` and `M`. And `M` has children `F`, `B` and `A` has children `D`,`Y` what would your expected order be? Better to add a sample input and expected output as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So question is if for example you have Bill as parent with 3 children Anna, Veronica and Georgia and Veronica has two children Bobby and Matthew, and you select Bill it should display:

1. Anna
2. Bill
3. Bobby
4. Georgia
5. Matthew
6. Veronica

But if you select Veronica it should display:

1. Bobby
2. Matthew
3. Veronica

?

Comment: If you select Bill's child list it should show his children in order
1. Anna,
2. Georgia
3. Veronica

And the chindren list of Veronica should be
1. Bobby
2. Mathew

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sort (Person person) {
        if (person.getChild() != null && !person.getChild().isEmpty()) {
            // Sort the child
            Collections.sort(person.getChild());
            
            // Sort for each child as parent
            for (Person child : person.getChild()) {
                sort(child);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

To test this

```
public void testPersonsSort() {
        Person bill = new Person();
        bill.setName("Bill");
        
        Person georgia = new Person();
        georgia.setName("Georgia");
        
        Person anna = new Person();
        anna.setName("Anna");
        
        Person veronica = new Person();
        veronica.setName("Veronica");
        
        List<Person> billsChild = new ArrayList<Person>();
        billsChild.add(georgia);
        billsChild.add(anna);
        billsChild.add(veronica);
        
        bill.setChild(billsChild);
        
        Person mathew = new Person();
        mathew.setName("Mathew");
        
        Person bobby = new Person();
        bobby.setName("Bobby");
        
        List<Person> veronicaChild = new ArrayList<Person>();
        veronicaChild.add(mathew);
        veronicaChild.add(bobby);
        veronica.setChild(veronicaChild);
        
        PersonSort personSort = new PersonSort();
        personSort.sort(bill);
        
        System.out.println(bill);
        
    }
```

output with each person and child sorted when non null

```
Person [name=Bill, child=[Person [name=Anna, child=null], Person [name=Georgia, child=null], Person [name=Veronica, child=[Person [name=Bobby, child=null], Person [name=Mathew, child=null]]]]]
```